# Going crazy here, can't figure out why rename(), copy() functions don't work

Tags: php, debugging

Here is what I have,

```
$name = "image.jpeg";
$to = "/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/termination_files/personal_photos/original/".$name;    
$from = "/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/public/userimages/original/".$name;
```

and

```
rename($from,$to);
```

or

```
copy($from,$to);
```

Shouldn't this work?! Directory permissions are set to 755, paths are copied from ssh, so they're accurate. Files exist in the from location.

Comment: can you give more clue about the error message you've got? Or what you have versus what you're expecting to have?

Comment: @Skrol29
Warning: copy(/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/termination_files/personal_photos/original/153.jpeg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/controllers/WorkController.php on line 31
--
Permissions are set to 775 to all folders. It will only work if I set permissions to 777, but that's wrong to set right?

Comment: You have no other choice anyway. Nothing extremely wrong with 777 though. If you're using shared hosting, your data is not that important anyway

Comment: I am using dedicated hosting, and this is a very important project, I have this function working on another controller but it won't work here. I don't understand why.

Comment: My ftplogin is owner of the script being executed, and all the directories involved.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be using incorrect file permissions.

'5' means 'read and execute'. So if the webserver isn't the owner of the destination, it won't be able to write the new file out to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Don't other people. Ask your server.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Put these lines at the top of your code and see what error occurred. Then correct it.