# Getting permissions error with php copy function. chmod

Tags: php, debugging, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Going crazy here, can't figure out why rename(), copy() functions don't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538966/going-crazy-here-cant-figure-out-why-rename-copy-functions-dont-work)

I get this error:

Warning: copy(/fullpathtofile/a4d3af69.jpeg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/controllers/WorkController.php on line 31

Permissions are set to 775. It will only work with 777, but I don't think that's the right way to go for my social network site which is on my dedicated server, it's a safety issue right? Is that my only fix? I expected copy() should have worked.

Comment: Why do you ask (almost) the same twice a day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538966/going-crazy-here-cant-figure-out-why-rename-copy-functions-dont-work btw it says: permission denied which is self-explanatory.

Comment: Because the answers didn't tell me how to resolve it :) I've been looking. Maybe you can resolve it? All permissions are for same user, 775 chmod. What more could it ask for?

Comment: this is definitely not the way how this site is working. Sorry, voting for close.

Comment: Go ahead, no hard feelings. Obviously it helped people get further into the issue to show that even with permissions granted it isn't running the function. In the other one we weren't capable of getting that deep.

Comment: I feel that this should be reopened, as the question linked to does not provide any useful answer IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web server user does not have sufficient permissions to write to the directory you are *copying to*.

### Walkthrough for solving your problem

1. `chmod` the "target" directory to `777`.
2. Let your script write a file to that directory.
3. Inspect the written file (`ls` will do) and see *which user owns it*.
4. That is the user the web server process is running as.
5. Make sure your target directory *is owned by that user* (in which case `chmod 755` will do) or *that user's group* (in which case `chmod 775` will do).

Comment: How do I figure out what permissions the "web server user" has? I thought the chmod 755 took care of that. Where and how to change that?
edit: I just did get_current_user(), and the owner of the directory is same as the owner of the script, so it should've worked shouldn't it have?

Comment: @Darius: Is the target directory **owned** by the web server user?

Comment: Yes. Here is what i have for results folder (target) termination_files/original chmod is owner: myftplogin group: psacln (my from folder) public/userimages is owner: myftplogin group: psacln. I ran get_current_user(); it says owner is : myftplogin. So

Comment: @Darius: `get_current_user` returns the owner of the PHP script that is executing -- **not the user as which the web server process is running**.

Comment: Alright, so i created a new textfile with fwrite(), and turns out the owner is : apache and group is apache. I didn't know the server ran it's own process username, thought it used mine. What you're telling me now is I have to change the webserver username and to myftplogin and group. This should solve the problem and not cause further issues I suppose. Then I will be able to set the permission to 755 and it will work?

Comment: @Jon got your update, many thanks. Did the test/walkthrough you provided.

Comment: @Darius: Don't change the web server's user. Just `chown` the target directory appropriately, or add `apache` to the `psalcn` group.

Comment: @Jon Thank you for your patience. You were able to tell me what was wrong and where to look for the issue. I learned lots of new things from this today thanks to you. It seems to work now with permission set to 775.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions of what are set to 775? If it is the target, you would need write-permission, otherwise you can't write to that location?

Comment: the permissions to both my receiving folder and my taken out of folder are set to that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ownership of your /fullpathtofile to the user who is running the webserver, and the same is true for the files within it. All files which are saved from PHP will be owned by that user. I am assuming you are saving an uploaded file to that directory: otherwise this holds for both the source and the destination.

Comment: all directories are owned by my ftp login, and all directories are owned by my ftp login, so shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

`chown` the relevant directory to be owned by the user that the PHP script runs as (see [get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php)).

**Edit:** This is wrong, see comments. The user you actually want to use with `chown` is the one the web service is running as. This is commonly `nobody`, `apache`, `www-data`, etc., and can usually be determined with `ps aux | grep httpd`.

Comment: The owner matches up with the /fullpath's directory owner.

Comment: @Darius are you certainly sure?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Positive, that's why I don't understand it. termination_files/original chmod is owner: myftplogin  group: psacln   my public/userimages is owner: myftplogin group: psacln.   I ran get_current_user(); it says owner is : myftplogin.

Comment: -1: This is misleading: `get_current_user` returns the owner of the PHP script that is executing -- **not the user as which the web server process is running**.

Comment: @Dae: Downvote removed after update.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on dedicated, there is nothing wrong with 777 then.

You have to check perms and owner for the every nested directory involved.

`ls -la` them all.